# Facebook Feed Dialog simplified?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, share, feed

I'm trying to add a share button or "feed dialog" as Facebook now seem to be pushing, to posts on my website. I'm basically looking for a way to simply allow users to click the button and be sent to the share preview page to post to their timeline or a friend's timeline etc.

The problem is that I don't really need an app (or at least I don't see the need in an app) and I'd like to avoid using their deprecated sharer url method.

What are my options? Can I use the feed dialog method without creating an app? I've tried going through their documentation but it just confuses me.

I'm not fussed whether it's JavaScript that opens a popup or if it redirects to a separate page (provided a redirect url can be provided to return users to the original page on my website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you definitely need an app for the FB.ui feed dialog, but the user does not have to be logged in. Without an app, you can either use the sharer.php in a javascript popup, or you can use a like and/or send button. Just make sure to include Open Graph metadata in your page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

Be aware that you should also use an app (id) with the like or send button.

Comment: Thanks! I got it more or less working using Feed Dialog but I'm getting '#_=_' appended to the end of both cancel and successful-post uris. I don't think I'm missing a parameter though.. I had a quick Google but I don't really understand what's going on! Any idea?

Comment: what exactly gets appended? is it a "ref" parameter?

Comment: #_=_

That is EXACTLY what's appended. It looks like it's supposed to be a pre-constructed anchor parameter but it's been given nothing so instead is returning underscores as "NULL" or something.

I didn't even ask for this though and Facebook's dev documentation is a mess. Nothing about it at all. The guys from CodeIgniter should rewrite it for them.

Have you seen this before? I had a quick Google but nothing I found seemed to be concrete. All seemed to be suggestions as to what it MIGHT be.

Comment: it looks weird indeed, but i would not worry too much about it. did you try with a real app too?

Comment: If by "real app" you mean a Facebook app for the URL/site then yes, it was relatively simple, just had to put in a few urls and wait about 10 minutes for them to propagate through Facebook's server.

I was mainly worried about the #_=_ causing issue with CodeIgniter's uri system but I've now discovered that CodeIgniter's controllers parse that fine, even if appended without a trailing slash! CI surprises me every day.

Comment: if it is not a problem, i would not care too much about it then. i guess i´ll also try CI soon, a lot of people keep telling me that it´s cool...

Comment: You should, it's fantastic. And their documentation is the best I've seen in a LONG time. Clear, concise (but thorough) and extremely well laid out.

Anyway, thanks for your help!